# Remove all duplicate numbers in ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have some problem with follow code. I must remove all duplicate numbers in ArrayList and print them. For exemple: Input: 11123345 Output: 245. Тhis code removes all repetitions but leaves one of them: Input: 11123345 Output: 12345;

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Number: ");

        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (num > 0)
        {
            list.Add(num % 10);
            num /= 10;
        }

        list.Reverse();

        List<int> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();

        PrintValues(distinct);

        static void PrintValues(IEnumerable distinct)
        {
            foreach (object value in distinct)
                Console.Write("{0}", value);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Are you getting output 12345

Comment: Yes my output is 12345 (must be 245)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, answer by Rad would suffice your question.

Here is the complete working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Number: ");

        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (num > 0)
        {
            list.Add(num % 10);
            num /= 10;
        }

        list.Reverse();

            var distinct = list.GroupBy(x => x) 
                   .Where(y => y.Count() == 1) //It'll count numbers which have single number sequence like 1 2 3 ,etc. but for double number sequence like 22 33 44 ,etc. change Count() == 2                                            
                   .Select(y => y.Key).ToList();
            foreach (object value in distinct)
                Console.Write("{0}", value);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `list` has the values you want to remove duplicates for, this code should give you want you want

```
var distinct = list.GroupBy(x => x)         // Group by the items in the list
           .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)      // Filter only elements with a count of 1
           .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();    // Project them into a new list
```